# Magento Configurable Products and Custom Options

Tags: php, magento, product, configurable

I have a configurable product with two options associated to it. 
I added a custom option to the same product to allow a user to upload a file for +£50. However, choosing configurable options on the page always over-rides the custom option and they don't work together.

This is a problem with the base Magento install 1.9.2.2 and 1.7.0.2

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean, they don't work together. They do work together. what did you encounter as not working together ? could you brief on that part..

Comment: If you upload a file before selecting configurable options, it sets the price to be 0. If you choose config options at any point before or after uploading, the price doesn't recognise the file upload price increment AND doesn't push the file through to the order

Comment: that shouldn't be the case by default, have you made modifications regarding configurable products or custom options ?

Comment: It is possible that the code that handles the upload is resetting the prices. I would start there.